# Woocommerce rest API error cannot create resources when using POST

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, woocommerce, postman

I am using basic auth 1.0. The images are attach here with.The url is working fine with GET method but giving me following error on POST.

```
 {    
"code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_create",
"message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.",
"data": {
    "status": 401
}
```

}

Comment: stuck !!!! need help

Comment: Visit this:https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth/issues/35#issuecomment-244001216

Comment: Have you visited above link. Let me know if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Maybe show how you authenticate / pass your credentials?

Comment: yes I have already visited the link and nothing works for me there@Dungeon

Comment: I am authenticating using OAuth1.0 and and passing ccs and ck everything is working fine when use GET and I have given both permissions read/write.

Comment: these are the links to  the image  of postman @David
https://ibb.co/eiLqA8
https://ibb.co/dQVOV8
https://ibb.co/bYwmiT
https://ibb.co/kxnFco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives problem in http but works fine with SSL.